# Continental Divide Line

Tags: dynamical-systems, applications, gradient-flows

I'm looking for a formal mathematical definition and a proof to the fact that every continent (or an island) has a Continental Divide Line.

Should I assume a terrain is a continues function from R^2 to R (The height function)? A continent or an island is a closed segment within R^2, with height(x,y)=0 for all points along the border, height(x,y)>0 for all points in the continent, and height(x,y)=0 for all points outside the continent?

I'm thinking an "ocean" is a segment on the border.

Intuitively I know what the divide line is, but since it can go "crazy", I'm not sure how to define it.

Can this phenomenon be extended to any manifold in a topological space?

Comment: I'm not sure that the word manifold is appropriate here. This seems more like a problem of measure (well, you need to figure out your definitions first).

Comment: This seems like a great problem for the intermediate value theorem! I agree with hoot- I'm not totally sure what a continental divide line is mathematically, and I bet other people would find it helpful to understanding the question. If you could add that, I think it would improve your question.

Comment: The intermediate value theorem deals with this case (two dimensions) well enough. More generally there's the [ham sandwich theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_sandwich_theorem).

Comment: There is an essay on the mathematics of the continental divide in Brian Hayes, Group theory in the bedroom, and other mathematical diversions, Hill and Wang, New York, 2008, ISBN: 978-0-8090-5219-6; 0-8090-5219-9.

Comment: The chapter originally appeared as Dividing the Continent in American Scientist 88, No. 6 (November-December 2000) starting on page 481. This may be freely available on the web. See also http://bit-player.org/2009/long-division

Comment: Before asking about divide lines you should formulate some criteria according to which you want to divide your continent or island. E.g., dividing ${\mathbb C}$ according to which solution of $z^3-1=0$ a given initial point $z_0$ is attracted by Newton's method leads to a very strange partition of ${\mathbb C}$.

Comment: Have you had a look at any of the Hayes material, Uri?